# Submit iframe and parent form by submit button in parent page

Tags: html

This is my parent form parent-form.html with one submit button.

```
    <form name="parent_form">
    Name
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" type="button"  value="Submit"></button>
    </form>

    <iframe src="iframe_form.html" id="iframe_id" name="iframe_name"></iframe>
```

This is my iframe form iframe_form.html with one field in it.

```
    <form name="iframe_form">
     Address
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
    </form>
```

I want to submit both address field of iframe as well as name field of parent-form by clicking submit button of parent form.

There were other post related but none appropriate with simple method.

Comment: Why, oh why, oh why, oh why are you using an IFRAME for content hosted on the same domain (the relative src path for the IFRAME) ?

Comment: i tried .load() of jquery to load iframe_form.html but it does not seem to work on chrome. More over i have minimized the content. I had to use iframe because there is tab within tab so coding became quite complex.

Comment: You didn't have to use an IFRAME "because it became quite complex". Try again. If you have difficulties with the normal, sane ways of embedding content, *then* ask questions about those ways!

Comment: Please provide me with some examples to embed content like iframe and .load(). I have to load different html pages in side the tab

Comment: No. Ask the relevant question (a *new* one). Feel free to either continue with this line of questioning, or delete the question.

Comment: It'd be tricky to find anything more complicated than having an iframe form inside a regular form. In fact, most form elements are hidden with CSS rather than loaded externally.

Comment: Insane, but <form onsubmit="this.hiddenField.value=window.frames['iframe_name'].document.iframeform.address.value"

Comment: Only parent form is submitting with name field.

Comment: @user3131520. Yes because form-submittion (in the parent window) is asynchronous from the IFRAME's perspective. By the time it completes, the IFRAME no longer exists, and so can't do its own POST.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with iFrames but in this case, it's not efficient or easy.

If you want to avoid the problem of frames and forms, then use a scrollable division:

```
    <div id="scrollcontent1" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:100px;">
      Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
    </div>
```

If you want to have more than one on your page, use a sequence of them making sure the ID has a different name for each. You can then dynamically present what you need using the `visible` property and whatever javascript triggers you desire. Make sure you set the `height` property and if you want both scrollbars present, use `overflow` instead of `overflow-y`. It's a simple solution and it avoids the headaches of jquery as well as iframes.

Ihope you will get better mileage out of a helpful answer than and snobbish "ask the right question".

Comment: Upvoted because your right, there are way too many douchy snobbish users that just waste time posting argumentative replies instead of HELPING! these users need to JOG THE HELL ON!!!! rant over